# Passing CSV to Mysql Stored Procedure: WHERE IN (CSV)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, denormalization

i've been thinking about Denormalizing data in response to alot of traffic. There are some obvious tricks - keeping counts in another table and using transactions to minimize "seek" times.

So in that, i was considering a system in which a multiple users could have multiple Friends. And say if you had a million users, you could have a very large table to go through each time you wanted to load friends. In that, i would use a table that contained a friend event for each interaction. Also a sender and recipient field. In this there would still be alot of potential records / traffic.

Now i don't know a whole lot about about SQL tuning or when denormalizing is to much but i was wondering does it make sense to store a quick list of a users friends as CSV (Manage this on friend event change - within transaction) then pass it off to myqsl? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM FRIENDS WHERE ID IN (1,2,3)
```

Now, to prevent SQL injections MySQL upon running the statement removes all but the first item in the CSV so it would only scan 1. Obviously there for a good reason.

Now, this query is always system initiated (No input from the user) so the input should be clean / not subject to injection so i can implement this as an unfiltered query. Not calling a stored procedure....?....

How does this sound? IN this case, and scaling up - does the IN CLAUSE make sense? Can MySQL handle to many calls to so many records?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An IN statement with a large number of values isn't particularly inefficient; but most databases have a limit on the size of the query statement, and use of IN with thousands of values can easily "break" that query size limit; but if those values come from another db query, then typically you can use a JOIN instead to make it more efficient, and avoid breaking the query limit

Comment: And an IN statement isn't running additional queries for each individual value in the IN statement; it's just a single database query

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.